# French Press: Does "plunge speed" affect taste?

Tags: french-press

Recently at the office a fellow co-worker of mine got a french press. I see that he slowly plunges the grinds down to the bottom as the roast brews.

Does this really affect the flavor of the coffee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plunging speed will only change the flavour in a minor way. Plunging slowly/carefully will prevent more sediment from getting through the filter as you push it down. Change in amount of sediment in your cup will change the mouth feel of your coffee, and may influence the flavour a little bit. I.e.: If there is too much sediment it may be more bitter.

I have found I do not even need to plunge at all when making French Press, I have started simply carefully pouring the coffee out through the filter without plunging.

[Link](https://youtu.be/r5_NpFJaApI) to cat video performing the French Press method described above.

See [answers](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/does-french-press-plunger-speed-affect-the-taste?rq=1) to a previously posted question on this topic as well!

Comment: By pouring without plunging, do you get less grinds in the actual coffee?

Comment: Exactly. Plunging actually stirs up the grinds again while just carefully pouring doesn't. It might be a bit more wasteful in the end, but you could always plunge after serving the cups and drink the rest afterwards.

Comment: I have also found that the type of French Press and how full things are do affect this plunging affect.  Yes, plunging speed doesn't directly affect taste, but if you plunge too fast and the grounds are not sized right or its a very tight seal, more can potentially slip through.  I had a Bodum Travel Mug French Press and that was a very tight seal, so if I plunged too fast, the pressure wouldn't force water and such through the screen but around the sides causing coffee grinds to enter my cup of coffee.  The same could be true for other types as well.

Comment: if you don't put too much coffee in, the plunger will almost descend on its own (stirring up almost nothing). I can usually push mine down with the barest pressure from a finger tip as long as I wait a moment or two.

Comment: @bigadmouse I agree not much pressure should be needed, even a pinky finger is often enough!